# Vaadin @Javascript : clear cache for updated JS file

Tags: javascript, vaadin

I have a @JavaScript annotation in my application to load a .js file from the classpath.

Now I've made an update to the file and redeployed (locally), but I always get the old version back.  I've tried reloading everything (ctrl+R, ctrl+F5) but that doesn't work and also I wouldn't want the users to have to do that.

A trick I used in the past (without Vaadin) was to append a request parameter with the version (e.g. ?version=1) and update that so that the URL changes.  But apparently that isn't allowed for the @JavaScript annotation (Vaadin doesn't even try to load the file).

Comment: Maybe your app is using the @PreserveOnRefresh annotation on the UI object?  This might prevent Vaadin from reloading any JS.

Comment: No, I'm not using @PreserveOnRefresh.  Besides, I had restarted the server so that wouldn't have made a difference.  I've currently just changed the filename (added _vxxx where xxx is a number) and that works.

Comment: so you are saying, that even a server restart kept the "old" file?  could you do a `find` for the file in your target-dir?  could be, that it's there several times (e.g. once from your ide and once from your build tool).  if both are in the classpath only one get picked up.

Comment: well, at least now that I have renamed the file, there's no file with the old name lying around.  Before the rename, I did check the file in the `target` folder and it had the new contents, but still I was getting the old contents in the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have overcome this by utilizing the `resourceCacheTime` parameter of the Vaadin servlet configuration:

```
@VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, resourceCacheTime = 0)
```

**Although** it has its limitation as described in my answer to [another question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36473854/5074540).

Answer (score 1):

This is browser feature to localy cache JS files, nothing to do with Vaadin.

As you figure it out yourself: If you want to make sure users have latest version of JS file, you should rename JS file name to: `script_buildNumber.js`.

Comment: I don't agree that this has nothing to do with Vaadin: there are ways for web applications to tell the browser e.g. not to cache certain resources.  I came up with the answer of renaming the file myself but that's really a hack.  At least being able to add a request parameter would prevent me from having to change the actual name of the file in version control.

Comment: after a restart of the container, the new file is definetly loaded fresh from disc and a CTRL-F5 reload at least in Fx in default config will pull the new file.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Chrome's incognito feature (and not use it when visiting spicy/unpleasant websites).

Just open your browser in Incognito mode https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?hl=en and the browser will cache nothing.

Other browsers have this feature as well (Opera, IE, Firefox, Safari).

Comment: I wouldn't want my users to have to visit my web app in incognito mode to ensure they have the latest javascript files.  Vaadin should provide a way to tell the browser not to cache them, or support adding request parameters to the name so files don't have to be physically renamed.

Comment: Sure, I agree with you, I thought you need it only for development.

Answer (score 0):

As I noted in my comment on the question on January 12th, renaming the file worked.  This seems to be currently the only way, although it's far from ideal.